# Rust libgit2: how to add --force

Tags: git, rust, libgit2

How to do a `git add --force *` with libgit2 in Rust?

I tried the following code from the [documentation](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Index.html#example):

```
use git2::{Index, IndexAddOption, Repository};

let repo = Repository::open("/path/to/a/repo").expect("failed to open");
let mut index = repo.index().expect("cannot get the Index file");
index.add_all(["*"].iter(), IndexAddOption::DEFAULT, None);
index.write();
```

and it seems to work. Then I replaced `IndexAddOption::DEFAULT` to `IndexAddOption::FORCE` and I get the following error (example from a test on the Linux Kernel source code):

```
Error { code: -1, klass: 10, message: "invalid path: 'arch/i386/'" }', src/main.rs:58:14
```

What I understand is that when I use `FORCE`, it will add "files" that are "non-standard" (like binaries or even directories) for git. That's why it is trying to add a directory and raises the *invalid path* error.

I just would like to implement a `git add --force *` using libgit2 API in Rust. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `**/*` or `.` in place of `*`?

Comment: Yes but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to define a [callback function `IndexMatchedPath`](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/type.IndexMatchedPath.html) like in [this example](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs/blob/d5a56e9be2b3d708748946ca0b9dfba00835eac0/examples/add.rs#L41).

Using this function raises the same error with a precision that it is from `git.status_file()`. In fact, on [Line 42](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs/blob/d5a56e9be2b3d708748946ca0b9dfba00835eac0/examples/add.rs#L42) of the previous example, we have this line:

```
        let status = repo.status_file(path).unwrap();
```

First, to remove the error, we can check if `path` is a directory or not. We can ignore if it is a directory like mentioned in the [documentation of `git2::IndexMatchedPath`](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/type.IndexMatchedPath.html):

> Return 0 to confirm the operation on the item, > 0 to skip the item,
> and < 0 to abort the scan.

However, we still have the error with `if path.is_dir() { 1 }else {...}`. Hence, just extracting the string with `path.to_str().unwrap()` and testing if it `ends_with("/")` seems to work. Our function looks like this:

```
        let cb = &mut |path: &Path, _matched_spec: &[u8]| -> i32 {
            if path.to_str().unwrap().ends_with("/") { 1 }else{
                let status = self.repository.status_file(path).unwrap();
                ...
        };
```

Now that we removed the error, we move to the implementation of `--force`. In the example, it checks the status of the files to add:

```
        let ret = if status.contains(git2::Status::WT_MODIFIED)
            || status.contains(git2::Status::WT_NEW)
```

It adds modified or new files (more info [here](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Status.html)). So, in addition of modified and new files, we can include *ignored* files with [`git2::Status::IGNORED`](https://docs.rs/git2/latest/git2/struct.Status.html#associatedconstant.IGNORED):

```
        let ret = if status.contains(git2::Status::WT_MODIFIED)
            || status.contains(git2::Status::WT_NEW)
            || status.contains(git2::Status::IGNORED)
```

So now, we use `IndexAddOption::FORCE` and `cb`:

```
index.add_all(["*"].iter(), IndexAddOption::FORCE, Some(cb as &mut git2::IndexMatchedPath));
```